# Empty StackOverflow Exception when running a mono app that accesses a shared object

Tags: c#, c++, mono

I'm currently trying to convert this project (https://github.com/hzeller/rpi-rgb-led-matrix) to a library. It's a sample to control Adafruit's 32x32 RGB LED Matrix via a Raspberry Pi. Because I'm a professional .NET-Developer, I thought about creating my first Mono project. So I thought about converting the sample to a library.

First steps first, I only wanted to start the main routine simply by my mono tool, but I fail miserably.

I get an empty error message when running the program, just saying "Stack Overflow: ". And that's it. I'm actually pretty lost here, because C++ is not really my main language. What am I doing wrong? It should be as simple as "Hello World", I guess.

My try: https://github.com/DanielGilbert/rpi-rgb-led-matrix

My mono app: https://github.com/DanielGilbert/Chronos

Comment: Not a C++ guy either, so just some comments. First, I don't know the .lo file you're importing. Can you explain? Check the import path. A Stackoverflow usually means cyclic code. That it doesn't contain a message and stacktrace can maybe be explained by your app quitting very fast, as there's no loop or process started.